# Odoo - How to add custom field attribute without modifying by extending

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I am trying to use my custom attribute for fields called `sf_group`. Unfortunately, this attribute is shown when getting field description via `fields_get()`. Is there a way to add this attribute to the field description? I need to check if this attribute is on the field and what's its value on the JS side.

Note: [Odoo - add custom field attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742506/odoo-add-custom-field-attribute) didn't help because it only works if you modify the source code which is something I don't want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer!

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Company(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.company"
    test_field = fields.Char(string="Test Field", custom_attr="random01")
    def _valid_field_parameter(self, field, name):
        return name == 'custom_attr' or super()._valid_field_parameter(field, name)
    @api.model
    def fields_get(self, allfields=None, attributes=None):
        fields = super().fields_get(allfields=allfields, attributes=attributes)
        for key in fields.keys():
            if key in self._fields and hasattr(self._fields[key], 'custom_attr'):
                fields[key]['custom_attr'] = self._fields[key].custom_attr
        return fields
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you!! Despite your lack of information, it has worked perfectly for me.
It is clear that one needs to understand well before using it, and why he would need such an action

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new `Char`field and set the attribute and its description there.

**Example:**

```py
from operator import attrgetter
from odoo import models, fields


class Char(fields.Char):
    custom_attr = None

    _description_custom_attr = property(attrgetter('custom_attr'))


class Company(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.company"

    test_field = Char(string="Test Field", custom_attr="random01")
```

The new attribute will be automatically available in the field description:

Comment: Note that the field ``type`` is ``char``, it didn't change.